# jShowOff - Numeric links show 'undefined' ( in wordpress )

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-plugins

i searched and searched, the only thing i found relative to this situation was the fact that jQuery is under 1.6, that i believe wordpress has way above that.... i built a jShowOff Content Rotator on a Wordpress site, and i wanted to have numeric slide links, as i tought it would show by default but instead shows 'undefined' in each link.... i tryed a workaround by making a counter and giving the title that counter, works like a charm but when you get the mouse over the Content Rotator it pops the counter as title xD looks damm ugly.... any ideas? here is the code:

```
<div id="recentes">
                <?php $my_query = new WP_Query('category_name=oficiais&posts_per_page=7');
                    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
                    $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID; ?>
                    <div><p>
                    <?php the_post_thumbnail('recent-thumbnail',array('title' => "")); ?>
                    <span class="recentes_tit"><?php the_title(); ?></span><br /><p><?php $myExcerpt = get_the_excerpt();
                    $tags = array("<p>", "</p>");
                    $myExcerpt = str_replace($tags, "", $myExcerpt);
                    $myExcerpt = str_replace("<br />", " ", $myExcerpt);
                    echo $myExcerpt;
                    ?></p class="content_readmore"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Ver artigo</a></p></div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                </div>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    jQuery(document).ready(function(){ jQuery("#recentes").jshowoff({
                        autoPlay:true,
                        changeSpeed:1500,
                        controls:true,
                        effect:"slideLeft",
                        hoverPause:true,
                        speed:4500,
                    }); });
                </script>
```

just for the information, assume i called the jShowOff css and script x) Thank you in advance =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I happened to have very same problem today.  Have googled and got this link: https://github.com/ekallevig/jShowOff/issues/38

saying:

change line 231 of jquery.jshowoff.js from :

```
var linktext = $(this).attr('title') != '' ? $(this).attr('title') : i+1;
```

to:

```
var linktext = $(this).prop('title') != '' ? $(this).prop('title') : i+1;
```

in my case this worked.